# How to stop running my terraform commands with a service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

```
gcloud auth list
    Credentialed Accounts ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       xxxx@xxxx.com

To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT
```

The credentials used here are correct and make sense, but when I run it HOPING it to be that user account, the error is saying that this service account does not have permissions needed in this environment. Which makes total sense! but! I can't figure out how to stop terraform from running as this service account and not as my own active user account.

> Error: Error loading state: Failed to open state file at
> gs://dxxxxdefault.tfstate: googleapi: got HTTP response code 403 with
> body: `AccessDenied`Access
> denied.terraform-win@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com
> does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage
> object.

Comment: Try **gcloud auth application-default revoke**.

Comment: If you are using service account impersonation, try *gcloud config unset auth/impersonate_service_account* Also run *gcloud auth revoke --all* after the app-default revoke command.

Answer (score 1):

The error message said that your service account `terraform-win@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com` cannot access terraform state on Google Cloud Storage, you just need to add `storage.objects.get` permission to the service account to fix the error.

If you don't want Terraform to use this service account, you can remove [impersonation settings in Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference#impersonate_service_account) and [environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/getting_started#adding-credentials).